# Typescript definition for a function which returns based on nested keys in parameter

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm trying to write a declaration file for a library we're using without any means to modify it.

The way it works is that you can send a configuration object, the return will be based on some keys inside of it

```
const args = {
  // ...
  resources: {
    One: {
      query: { url: 'value' }
    }
  } 
}

library(args)
```

Invoking it returns an object with the deeply nested keys of `resources` as functions

```
const ret = {
  One: {
    query: async (query) => <data>
 }
}

// ret.One.query(args) => data
```

Ideally each `<data>` would also be typed, I'm not sure if this is possible due to the dynamic keys? I've tried a couple of approaches using `keyof` the parameters without any luck

Edit: Updated example

```
const config = {
  // ...
  resources: {
    User: {
      find: { url: 'http://example.com/userapi' }
    },
    Dashboard: {
      update: { method: 'post', url: 'http://example.com/dashboardapi'}
    }
  } 
}

const services = serviceCreator(config)

// service creator turns the supplied resources object into promise functions

await services.User.find({id: '123'}) // Promise<User>
await services.Dashboard.update({user: '123', action: 'save'}) // Promise<Dashboard>
```

Comment: What would the type of `<data>` be? Depending on the keys I assume, but how? Also, is the type of `query` parameter `any`?

Comment: This question would really benefit from including a [mcve], since it's not clear what the input and output types should be.  Does the input always have a `resources` property?  Do the properties of the `resources` property always contain a `query` property?  And what are the input and output types of the async `query` in the output?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. <data> in this case is an API response so a generic. The configuration always contains `resources` and accepts a `query` parameter which is basically the body for POST. I'll update the example.

Comment: Extended the example

Comment: You'll need a separate mapping from the names `User` and `Dashboard` to the *types* `User` and `Dashboard`, as you can't do such things programmatically in TypeScript.  So, for example, you'll need something like `interface Resources { User: User; Dashboard: Dashboard }`.

Comment: That was my worry. Thanks @jcalz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without further information, I'm guessing that you're looking for something like this:

```
type Arg<T> = { resources: T; }
type Ret<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: {
        query: (...query: any[]) => Promise<any>;
    }
}
declare const library: <T>(arg: Arg<T>) => Ret<T>;
```

Let's test it to see if it works:

```
const args = {
    resources: {
        One: {
            query: { url: 'value' }
        }
    }
}
var ret = library(args);

async function test() {
    await ret.One.query();  // OK
}
```

You can try it in this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggJwOYB4AqA+GBeGBvASASgGcB7AVwQGNSAuGNAbhgF9RJYAlKEdLXHmAEA2gGkYASwB2MANZQwZAGaMAugyEECARwpQEYBgAoAdOb0GjMAIbSwItQEocWAAoIyAW0kkoKOzAMJmF2dgATKGoAGxtiGGoyaRIQGGjJACMEOOt+YzikBkRUTBdsLB4+TBDgROTUgpIcfGFicipaEk1hAgB5aShu7V19Q00YKmiGAHIANxto-Wm2HvYCMOB5hBhiVNx0rJz85BInGpsSMGlqGGUKa5BJJJgQUhBjFy0bAHcbSVTdqZ+lBTJZDB8mAQAPRQmC9MTAVhAA).

Comment: Thanks. I updated the example a bit but this helps a long way.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly new to TS & find this question really interesting. Here's my take on it, it's fairly verbose & require a *weird* type input. However it gets pretty good type suggestion. I would love feedback from more experienced users:

```js
/**
 * map dynamic resource type to method name,
 * i.e 'User' -> 'find' | 'lookup'
 */
type MethodMap = Record<string, string>

interface ResourceParams {
  url: string;
  method?: 'GET' | 'POST' | 'PUT' | 'DELETE';
}

/**
 * Each method in resource type has interface ResourceParams
 */
type Resources<T extends MethodMap> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    [S in T[K]]: ResourceParams;
  }
}


interface Config<T extends MethodMap> {
  resources: Resources<T>;
  [key: string]: unknown;
}

type Result<T extends MethodMap> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    [S in T[K]]: () => Promise<any>
  }
}

declare const library: <T extends MethodMap>(config: Config<T>) => Result<T>

// usage

const result = library<{ User: 'find' | 'lookup'; Dashboard: 'search' }>({
  resources: {
    User: {
      find: { url: 'value' },
      lookup: { url: 'asdads', method: 'GET' },
    },
    Dashboard: {
      search: { url: 'value' }
    },
  } 
})

result.User.find() // OK
result.User.lookup() // OK
result.Dashboard.search() // OK

result.User.search() // Not OK
result.Dashboard.find() // Not OK
result.Store.find() // Not OK
```

[Link to playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAshwAsD2ATGBDMUC8UBKEAxkgE4oA8AzsCQJYB2A5gDRTV1MB8AUNw8BBIAzdIWgFKSAK4kxABXQl0AW0pQA3tyhQZAGwBcbGg0YBuLVGXxkKAPyGA5AHEAogBUHUAD5QHcgPIAyh7evnIAqiE+DgAiLgAy7i4O5gC+vKCQ+BCSMmKU5G5QEAAeAvQoanCIqBhgnDgaFgDaANJQDFAA1hAgSEJQbgC6hpra2s2BHfSDbUMj2bmyEApKquba6el89ALCotAAwkj0QrSMhcVlEBVV1rWYDWNQJDnSy5SGEu-5hZxpGXA4hyUl0wEupXKlVg9zQj0azza026vX6gwWzwmU06bjmCwAFABKHANOQkJDKWiUCDkdD0EA8TbcbYoIi6RTQYj0ahQXS0ABGShIIEMEOutxhNTh9XxXLOjEMx1O5z+xOwDQkoPBbh43C5PNelC1jT5gsUIHI6ig4WpJEcZwqnmiuiQSC6UjAKSgMXQlAQ-KQihQjmpikICE8qU4+Oehp+OVGFm0NsEifG4wdwY0OhIBl8ADd0LopBBI8wk+MXW6PaMc3mHL6UOhKg5WFYpY5XCFUuX0z2Kz6-QGg2n02wIGGELW9I5C8XS1B0n3e4uoMzCbxDVqAHQpkjbzNEqAAemPUH8rW4W7Bu9t26r7rAR9P58v1+A28H-sDZG3odkCDPmeF6biCN57n+E4AUBUAAHJIMAr5XmBH5fsOv6HsSL7wYhIHvtugTAKQEAHgwKAwThr5AA)